# Examples of Apps with PIN protected content

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

We have an iOS app with the following requirement.

- The app must be accessible only to those participating in a research study

The app will be published to the public App Store, however, it will launch with a lock screen. If a valid PIN code is entered, the lock screen will disappear to reveal the app.

We are looking for examples of other apps that follow a similar restricted-access model.

There are a lot of apps that require login prior to use. However, most of them also have a registration button, a preview mode, or provide unrestricted content. In our case, the PIN code will be provided in person to those participating in our research study.

We are look for examples to emulate so in order to avoid issues with the app review process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are for example apps from [Good Technology](https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/good-technology-inc./id328100528). You need a login and PIN from the admin in order to use the app. As for the review process You would need to provide the PIN to Apple in order to test the app (could be sample account).

Here's the info on [Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26) about test accounts in iTunes Connect under **App Review Information**.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](http://www.engadget.com/2015/10/30/google-whos-down-friend-finding-app/) recently released a [who's down](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whos-down-fall-2015/id968566099?mt=8) new app for iOS and Android platform. The app has invite code requirement to be able to use this. Basically ton off apps have invite code options to enable wait list. This is similar to functionality you need.